# Localization value in Android

Tags: android, localization

Can anybody tell  me what is the value we have write for spanish in android. For example we write the value for English is 'en' Chinese 'zh'. Then what is the value for Spanish...???

Thanx in Advance...!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanx to All,

Now I found Answer. That value is only 'es'. And I follow [this](http://developer.vodafone.com/how-support-multiple-languages-android/) documents.

Answer (score 0):

Its a,

- es - Spanish
- es_US - Spanish, US

Look at this link,

[Android Supported Language and Locales](http://colincooper.net/?p=238)

and

http://download1.parallels.com/SiteBuilder/Windows/docs/3.2/en_US/sitebulder-3.2-win-sdk-localization-pack-creation-guide/30801.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
Its Spanish (es_ES) . `Its supported from android version 1.5`
```

**Look at [this](http://colincooper.net/?p=238) link might help you a lot .**

You can find all the available Locale of the device using the following function.

```
Locale loc = new Locale("en");
Log.i("-------------",Arrays.toString(loc.getAvailableLocales()));
```

**Output**

```
I/-------------( 4390): [ar, ar_EG, bg, bg_BG, ca, ca_ES, cs, cs_CZ, da, da_DK, de, de_AT, de_BE, de_CH, de_DE, de_LI, de_LU, el, el_CY, el_GR, en, en
_AU, en_BE, en_BW, en_BZ, en_CA, en_GB, en_HK, en_IE, en_IN, en_JM, en_MH, en_MT, en_NA, en_NZ, en_PH, en_PK, en_RH, en_SG, en_TT, en_US, en_US_POSIX,
 en_VI, en_ZA, en_ZW, es, es_AR, es_BO, es_CL, es_CO, es_CR, es_DO, es_EC, es_ES, es_GT, es_HN, es_MX, es_NI, es_PA, es_PE, es_PR, es_PY, es_SV, es_US
, es_UY, es_VE, et, et_EE, eu, eu_ES, fa, fa_IR, fi, fi_FI, fr, fr_BE, fr_CA, fr_CH, fr_FR, fr_LU, fr_MC, gl, gl_ES, hr, hr_HR, hu, hu_HU, in, in_ID,
is, is_IS, it, it_CH, it_IT, iw, iw_IL, ja, ja_JP, kk, kk_KZ, ko, ko_KR, lt, lt_LT, lv, lv_LV, mk, mk_MK, ms, ms_BN, ms_MY, nl, nl_BE, nl_NL, no, no_N
O, no_NO_NY, pl, pl_PL, pt, pt_BR, pt_PT, ro, ro_RO, ru, ru_RU, ru_UA, sh, sh_BA, sh_CS, sh_YU, sk, sk_SK, sl, sl_SI, sq, sq_AL, sr, sr_BA, sr_ME, sr_
RS, sv, sv_FI, sv_SE, th, th_TH, tr, tr_TR, uk, uk_UA, vi, vi_VN, zh, zh_CN, zh_HK, zh_HANS_SG, zh_HANT_MO, zh_MO, zh_TW]
```